# How do you replace empty strings in sublists with '0'?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of sublists with each sublist having items within that are sometimes blank. I'd like to replace all of the blank items with '0'.

```
Original_List = [['Thomas Jefferson', '0.0', '0', '0', '6.0', '0', '12', '177', '0', '', '0', '', '', '', '24000.0', '', '', '0'], ['George Washington', '0.0', '0', '0', '0.0', '0', '0', '214', '6', '', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0'], ['Barack Obama', '2.0', '0', '0', '2.0', '0', '0', '525', '3', '', '0', '', '', '', '24000.0', '20000.0', '94000.0', '114000.0']]


Desired_List = [['Thomas Jefferson', '0.0', '0', '0', '6.0', '0', '12', '177', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '24000.0', '0', '0', '0'], ['George Washington', '0.0', '0', '0', '0.0', '0', '0', '214', '6', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['Barack Obama', '2.0', '0', '0', '2.0', '0', '0', '525', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '24000.0', '20000.0', '94000.0', '114000.0']]
```

I've tried:

```
  return [map(lambda List_Item: re.sub('','0',List_Item),subli) for subli in lst]
```

This ends up replacing the wrong items with zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty string is falsy value.

Using `or` operator, you can get `'0'` for empty string:

```
>>> '' or '0'
'0'
>>> '123' or '0'
'123'
```

---

```
>>> Original_List = [
    ['Thomas Jefferson', '0.0', '0', '0', '6.0', '0', '12', '177', '0', '', '0', '', '', '', '24000.0', '', '', '0'],
    ['George Washington', '0.0', '0', '0', '0.0', '0', '0', '214', '6', '', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0'],
    ['Barack Obama', '2.0', '0', '0', '2.0', '0', '0', '525', '3', '', '0', '', '', '', '24000.0', '20000.0', '94000.0', '114000.0']
]
>>> [[x or '0' for x in xs] for xs in Original_List]
[['Thomas Jefferson', '0.0', '0', '0', '6.0', '0', '12', '177', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '24000.0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['George Washington', '0.0', '0', '0', '0.0', '0', '0', '214', '6', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['Barack Obama', '2.0', '0', '0', '2.0', '0', '0', '525', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '24000.0', '20000.0', '94000.0', '114000.0']]
```

Comment: @thefourtheye, You're right. But all values in the question are strings.